# Operators in Lexical Analysis

Tags: token, lexical-analysis

I am revising some things on the compiler for an uni exam, and I wondered what ID an operator token had? For example...

```
float position, initial, rate;
position = initial += rate * 60
```

Token, Type;
position, ID;
=, =;
initial, ID;
+=, ??? (What type is this);
rate, ID;
*, *;
60, num;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that += isn't +=? I think it should be a standard defined operator just like + or =.

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3yx2xe3h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says that the compiler should choose the longest token possible (reading left-to-right), so your compiler shouldn't confuse i+=5 as two operators. The example they give is i+++j == (i++) + j.

Comment: I thought the type would indeed be '+=', how ever i wasn't sure if they would have an umbrella type, unlike the assignment of '=' on its own. Thanks for the MSDN link, presumably all lexical analysers make the longest possible 'Word', not just the C++?

Comment: Presumably; I'm far from an expert on the subject.